# How to add right side Slide Menu iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amslidemenu, mfslidemenu

I want to make a Slide Menu (both right & left side) in Storyboard. Here the left Side Menu panel is a `viewController` and an `UITableView` with `customCell` embedded in it to perform the menu style. I have followed a youtube ["tutorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ) and the left side panel working perfectly. But now I need to do the same thing for right side slide menu. Exact same thing.

When I connect the segue, the `sw_rear` storyboard segue identifier is used for the left menu and the `sw_front` storyboard segue identifier is used for the front `viewController`. Or the 1st `viewController` of the left silde menu list. But there has also a segue identifier in the main source file ("SlideOutMenuFiles") which is `sw_right`, and it never been used any where in the code. So I am assuming, it could be used to implement the right side sliding.

I try to implement it in right side but can't do it. If any one understand my want or familiar with the problem, any suggestion would be much appreciable. Thanks a lot for your time. Have a good day.

If you want ["here"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzbrr1aye9mmom8/SlideMenu.zip?dl=0) is my demo project. Take have a look.

**(Addition: Please don't suggest any 3rd party API. I already tried with them.)**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already did it for the left side, I am not sure what's the issue u are facing to implement the same for the right side.

Simple put another button in the `BangladeshViewController` and add its action to the `rightRevealToggle:` and also add a new controller for the right side menu and connect it with the `SWRevealViewController`, give the custom segue name as "sw_right".

Just exactly like you did for the left side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post. Yes, It works. I don't know why it was not working earlier. May be some mistake was happened by me. Bahuut Dhanneybad. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Right side menu:

1. Drag-and-drop new `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController` as per your need in Storyboard.
2. Link new `Controller` with Segue from `RevealViewController` as `SWRevealViewControllerSegue` as you already did for `MenuViewController` and give it id '`sw_right`'.
3. You are done.

Run the project and you can access new Right side menu by swipe left.

Comment: A lot of thanks for your answer. Yes, It is just like that you saying. I already solved it by Suresh's instruction. Bahuut Shukriya. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check 
[code here](http://code4app.net/ios/left-and-right-side-menu/5032f7ee6803fa5051000002)

or

[git code](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not in Storyboard.

Comment: @Tulon you want it in storyboad? Let me implement in your code and share it with you